# How to paint a wall contrasting colors

Tags: home, paint

I am about to renovate my room. A part of this plan includes painting all but one wall and the ceiling white, the other wall will be bright green. My walls are lightly textured and if this makes any difference, the original surface under most of the walls is plaster and lathe (with the exception of the wall being painted green, which is drywall). The surface I will actually be painting over will be the previous coating of yellow semi-gloss paint that is about 20 years old.

So here's my question... How do I get crisp, clean edges in the corners where two colors meet (keeping mind that these are semi-gloss walls and are textured)?

Comment: This doesn't need a life hack in the context of this site. This is a core skill regarding how house painting is done. You can ask about in our [Home Improvement DIY site](https://diy.stackexchange.com), but I would be very surprised if it hasn't already been asked/answered already. Good luck!

Comment: @RobertCartaino Aye... Didn't realize we had a home improvement site... I will definitely check there and see if this has already been asked. The only way I could see this possibly requiring a life hack is that since it is a textured wall, most people will recommend tape and that may not be good enough to seal a textured wall.

Comment: @L.B. I have textured walls. Be sure to mention that in your post. There are well-known solutions I wouldn't mind having on hand myself.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I have added that it is a textured wall... Does that seem like a reasonable Life Hackish question or should I still post it over on Home Improvement?

Comment: @L.B. IMO, this is better asked on home improvement.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Alright, will do that. Gonna copy this over and then delete this post

Answer (score 2):

When I painted a house we used paper tape:

Cover the edge of one wall with tape, so you can quietly brush the other wall, without worrying to get out of the lines. I used this trick between the wall and the ceiling, but it will work between any two surfaces.

[image]
<sub>[image source](https://www.makeit-loveit.com/home-improvement-painting-a-straight-line-on-textured-walls-a-pro-painters-secret/)</sub>

---

For example, this kind of [paper tape](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=paper%20tape&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL794IL794&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK1dq-h-LaAhUNZ1AKHbl5BLYQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=949#imgrc=sWVwKy4RjBxiQM:):

[image]